# Could not find tools.jar React Native Android In windows 10

Tags: android, react-native

guys . i just try to install react native in my laptop. i've followed all setup instruction but i stiil get those error .

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar
```

i used genymotion with os version 5.1.0, i've setup environment variable for android_home. Any idea what i miss here ?

[image: sdk manager]

Comment: Jre or jdk ? Version ?

Comment: installed already .. jdk1.8.0_66 & jre1.8.0_71

Answer (score 108):

Setting the missing "JAVA_HOME" system environment variable worked for me.

- Press WIN+Pause on keyboard.
- Click advanced system settings.
- Click "Environment variables".
- Click "New" under "System variables".
- Type "JAVA_HOME" in the *Variable name* field.
- Type the path to the JDK in the *Value* field. For me the correct path
  with short filename was "C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_66". Your path will vary depending on the installed version.
- Click OK, and OK in previous window too.
- Restart any command prompts or restart the computer.
- `react-native run-android` worked fine after that.

Answer (score 18):

Setting up appropriate JDK (not JRE. JRE does not have `tools.jar`) version (E.g. JDK 1.7x) path as the `JAVA_HOME` would resolve this issue.

Please check your computer's environment variables and set `JAVA_HOME` if it has not already been setup.

Comment: Java is weird. For centos you type `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk` to install *JRE* - not JDK. But it says in the name jdk?! To install JDK I also needed `sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`

Comment: @Adam dude, you just saved my day!!! They are really that WEIRD :|

Answer (score 6):

If you have the Android Studio embedded JDK, then it may cause conflicts. A workaround for this problem I've found is setting your JAVA_HOME to the default JDK location specified in Android Studio.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open Project Structure window.
3. Set your JAVA_HOME environment variable to the path specified under "JDK location".

Comment: I've had a similar issue as well. For some reason the Javac compiler targets the Java JRE, rather than the Java JDK specified at `JAVA_HOME`. Running `gradle build` outside of Android Studio did the trick for me

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna go on a long shot here.
There is a tools.jar in java libs folder.[the java sdk that is]

Usually all these frameworks and ides have a lib folder themselves. and it is missing said tools.jar. Just copy paste it there.

Comment: where do i have to copy tools.jar file ? in my react project folder ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while running react-native run-android it gave me the error tool.jar not found. i solved this by adding a single line mentioned below, in gradle.properties file which is in android project.
[image]
org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

Comment: For those using the JDK that comes with Android Studio, you should instead assign the value of `org.gradle.java.home` to the the JDK that Android Studio is using. You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47732595/8680805) answer (located in this question thread) to see where your Android Studio's JDK path is located. In my case it was at `D:\Android\Android Studio\jre`

Answer (score 3):

If this problem occurs for Windows, then the solution here is fairly simple.

## Install Chocolatey

- Follow the installation instructions on this page. https://chocolatey.org/install

## Install jdk8

Restart Command Prompt or Powershell as Administrator, and run:

```
choco install jdk8
```

Now if you run

`react-native run-android`

This error shouldn't show up.

Answer (score 2):

Find  and copy tool.jar from JDK path
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\lib\tool.jar

then paste it in JRE folder
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\lib

then delete build folder from your project/android/app/=>build

and then try react-native run-android

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another data point for people pulling their hair out. I think a java update may have messed up my environment that was working fine 2 months ago. The combination of what worked for me:

Set `JAVA_HOME` to `1.7`, NOT `1.8`.

I had 2 1.8 versions installed and neither worked.

Comment: jdk 1.8.0_71 (x64) as JAVA_HOME works for me, though it's the one and only version I've installed. I recently got a jre update and so have two versions of that installed as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is for Windows, but this is the first result for this error on Google, so for Linux this problem could be fixed with:

`sudo apt install default-jdk`

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted "**\react_native_project_path\android**" directory and run

```
    reactive-native android
```

then run ..

```
    reactive-native run-android
```

Then the error is gone

Comment: check your spelling. it's `react-native`, not `reactive-native`

Answer (score 0):

At first I have to tell you open your `CMD` Then write `java -version`  then write `javac -version` Then see IF you haven't them press `Win` + `pause` then click on `advance system setting` then click on `Environment variables` then in `system variables` Click on `New` Then write `JAVA_HOME` in variable name and in the second section write your `JDK` path and click ok then in  `system variable` click on `path` then click `edit` and then click on `New` and write `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` and click `ok` then `ok` and at the end if you want to check it open `CMD` again and write `java -version` and then `javac -version`  I hope this will work for you.