# JAVA_HOME is not set error, after running React-native app

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

PS C:\Users\Prabhudev\react-projects\react-native\myFirstApp> react-native run-android

info JS server already running.
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
>   Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
>   location of your Java installation.

error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

> error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: After installing the `JDK` you should set the `JAVA_HOME` variable. more info here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf59/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-792499849.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find tools.jar React Native Android In windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35278283/could-not-find-tools-jar-react-native-android-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Add the JDK and JRE paths to the System Variable "Path"
like below:
[image]

Secondly, Add the JAVA JDK path to the USER variable as JAVA_HOME. as shown below:
[image]

Restart the cmd and go to the app directory and run the app with react-native run-android 
Voila:
[image]